# Having Trouble Executing Python Code in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have been on a quest to automate reports by using Windows Task Manager + Python and recently wrote a script that I could use to run the .py file. However, in practice, it does not work. I've spent a good two days looking for an answer and trying different things, but cannot for the life of me figure this out.

The Scenario: I am trying to write a standalone executable python code that connects to a server, pulls data using SQL, and then makes a dataframe/pivot table that saves in a folder. This process is what I want to automate.

My current code sample is below

```
def module():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"

    conn = connect(host="url.com", port=xxxxxx)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = as_pandas(cursor)
    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime("%Y%m%d")

    df = data.loc[;,'date','stuff_and_thangs','column1','column2','column3']
    earliest_date = df['date'].min()
    latest_date = df['date'].max()
    df['stuff_and_thangs'] = df['stuff_and_thangs'].astype(float)
    df['stuff_and_thangs'] = df['stuff_and_thangs'].round(decimals = 2)
    df.sort_values(by = 'date', ascending = 'True')
    df.groupby(['date'], sort = True)['stuff_and_thangs','Column1','Column3']

    table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Column', 'Column1', 'Column3'], columns =['Column'], values =['Column3'], fill_value = 0)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\User\blahblahblah/ %s to %s.xlsx' % (earliest_date, latest_date))
    #Convert the dataframe pivot table to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='stuff_and_thangs')

    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
    writer.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from impala.dbapi import connect
    import datetime
    from impala.util import as_pandas
    module()
```

Extra details:

Let's say that my file name for the module code is called file.py and I have a batch file for the task scheduler to run set up like so (let's call the batch file "batch.bat"):

```
start C:\Python27\python.exe file.py
```

I've coded in Jupyter Notebook and have only now started to try and convert these into executable standalone modules. Are there any best practices I may be missing? I have tried looking into environment variables but, they seem to be set up perfectly fine. The code seems to work fine within the jupyter notebook IDE, but does not work once I make it into a python file.

Comment: When you want to run a Python script from the command line just navigate to the folder your script is located in, then run the script: `C:\MyFolder>python myscript.py`. Does this helps?

Comment: This I have been able to successfully do with no issue. However, when I try to schedule this in Windows Task Scheduler, I cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: What about this `start C:\Python27\python.exe C:\YourLocation\file.py`?

Comment: @Elmex80s, so this is my current setup right now, but when I try to run it, the command prompt immediately closes and the the query I need to run does not run. 

When I run the exact same code from Jupyter Notebook, it runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the absolute same problem. My programs starts in via Jupyter or Spyder but does not work properly on the Windows Task Scheduler.

As printing to stdout did not work, I made Python create files which helped me narrowing down the problem. Try this, it helped me figuring out that it was pandas that could not be imported:

```
t = open("text11.txt", "wb")
t.close()

import re

t = open("text12.txt", "wb")
t.close()

import pandas as pd

t = open("text19.txt", "wb")
t.close()
```

...

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that may be hampering your project. Task scheduler may not be running in the user security context you think it is. This depends on whether you selected "Run whether user is logged on or not", whether you select "Run with highest privileges", whether the user is actually logged on, and/or whether the user has the local policy set to allow the user to run batch files.

If you select "Run whether user is logged on or not" or you select "Run with highest privileges", the user context under which it runs will not have access to network resources. I'm only aware of two ways around this. Do not select either of those options and run the task on a machine with a user logged on that has access to the needed network resources or run it on the server supplying those resources to the network and reference them with local references, such as C:, D:, etc for Windows, rather than UNC's which may not be an option in the case of cloud storage.

[Scheduled Task Security Context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152(v=ws.11).aspx)

[Permissions To Run Batch job](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/959d905c-5f97-4b4e-a9bb-3c00f9754f0b/permissions-to-run-batch-job?forum=winserverNIS)

Comment: Running with "highest privileges" doesn't prevent network access; it uses the unrestricted linked token of an administrator account. This may be a problem for mapped network drives if you haven't configured the system policy to share DOS devices between a UAC restricted and unrestricted token. Without this policy setting, there's no link between the two logon sessions and associated DOS-device object directories.

Comment: Running regardless of the user being logged on is a `Batch` logon in session 0, so it requires `SeBatchLogonRight` (unrelated to cmd.exe batch scripts), which is normally granted to administrators. The token of the created process will contain the `NT AUTHORITY\BATCH` SID in its list of groups. If you store the password, the task scheduler service calls `LogonUserExExW` with the hash of the stored credential. Otherwise it does a service-for-user (S4U) logon via `LsaLogonUser`. An S4U logon session only allows using local system resources.